# Spring property is null in dependent maven project

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, properties-file

I have one main maven project(**MyProject**) and one dependent maven project(**MyDepProject**). I want to access the Spring property from properties file(myProps.properties) as define below in MyProject's config xml file as below

```
 <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:myProps.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

MyDepProject jar is added as a maven dependency to MyProject.I can read the value of the PROP file by @Value annotation tag in MyProject but I get null value for values present in myProps file in MyDepProject. I tried writing the same bean tag in MyDepProject as well. But no luck. I still get value as null. Can you please help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can import the configurations of **MyProject** into **MyDepProject** like this example:

```
<import resource="classpath:x.y.z.oduleA/MyDepProject.xml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan fro the reply. That didnt solve my issue. My issue is I have to put the properties file on server's config folder and access that file in my dependent project(MyDepProject). Can you please let me know how can I do that?

I tried below option in my java file in MyDepProject. But it is not working
  ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
   
   InputStream inStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/myprops.properties");

Comment: @user3044271 When you say 'server's config folder' - that sounds as though it's external to the application's classpath? Is this folder a separate area used for holding the properties files?

Comment: Hi Will, Yes the folder is separate from theclasspath

Comment: @user3044271 You can post your dependencies of both projects ? Can be a problem with your dependencies..